# How to use OpenCV functions in Keras Lambda Layer?

Tags: python, opencv, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to use a function that uses some OpenCV function on the image. But the data I am getting is a tensor and I am not able to convert it into an image.

```
def image_func(img):
     img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV) 
     img=cv2.resize(img,(200,66))
     return img

model=Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(get_ideal_img,input_shape=(r,c,ch),output_shape=(r,c,ch)))
```

When I run this snippet it throws an error in the `cvtColor` function saying that `img` is not a numpy array. I printed out `img` and it seemed to be a tensor.

I do not know how to change the tensor to an image and then return the tensor as well. I want the model to have this layer.

If I cannot achieve this with a lambda layer what else can I do?

Comment: which backend are you using Theano or Tensorflow? Note that by default tensorflow is the backend. So if you didn't change anything tensorflow is what you're using.

Comment: I am using tensorflow

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?, I'm facing a similar issue

Answer (score 5):

You confused with the symbolic operation in the `Lambda` layer with the numerical operation in a python function.

Basically, your custom operation accepts numerical inputs but not symbolic ones. To fix this, what you need is something like [`py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) in `tensorflow`

In addition, you have not considered the backpropagation. In short, although this layer is non-parametric and non-learnable, you need to take care of its gradient as well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
import cv2

def image_func(img):
    img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV) 
    img=cv2.resize(img,(200,66))
    return img.astype('float32')

def image_tensor_func(img4d) :
    results = []
    for img3d in img4d :
        rimg3d = image_func(img3d )
        results.append( np.expand_dims( rimg3d, axis=0 ) )
    return np.concatenate( results, axis = 0 )

class CustomLayer( Layer ) :
    def call( self, xin )  :
        xout = tf.py_func( image_tensor_func, 
                           [xin],
                           'float32',
                           stateful=False,
                           name='cvOpt')
        xout = K.stop_gradient( xout ) # explicitly set no grad
        xout.set_shape( [xin.shape[0], 66, 200, xin.shape[-1]] ) # explicitly set output shape
        return xout
    def compute_output_shape( self, sin ) :
        return ( sin[0], 66, 200, sin[-1] )

x = Input(shape=(None,None,3))
f = CustomLayer(name='custom')(x)
y = Conv2D(1,(1,1), padding='same')(x)

model = Model( inputs=x, outputs=y )
print model.summary()
```

Now you can test this layer with some dummy data.

```
a = np.random.randn(2,100,200,3)
b = model.predict(a)
print b.shape

model.compile('sgd',loss='mse')
model.fit(a,b)
```

Comment: Nice example, think that helps me a lot, even when tf 2.0 is out now haha. But i think you may have a typing error and not using your custom layer (f) at all, because you defined outputs=y , beforehand just passed x to y and so just skipped your Custom layer. Maybe i talk bul*****, but thanks for your explanation anyway ^^

Comment: This is an excellent explanation for neophytes in Keras and Tensorflow. Just change tf.py_func for tf.py_function (dropping stateful parameter) in newest version of Tensorflow. Thxs!!

Comment: I followed your template for a similar case where the image tensor has to pass through a transformation (color space, etc), and have been training it with a toy example. Without the custom layer the model trains and generalizes well, however when I use the custom layer the loss never decreases. What could be the problem? Maybe something related to the gradient flowin the custom layer? Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but you shouldn't use this trick unless the function that you are interested in is some kind of preprocessing, i.e. something can placed in between a raw RGB image and a DNN. If your task is about color space, you can always learn a simple 1x1 Conv2D layer for a color transform, e.g. YUV <> RGB.

Answer (score -1):

Im going to assume `image_func` function does what you want (resize) and image. Note that an image is represent by a numpy array. Since you are using the tensorflow backend you are operating over Tensors (this you knew).

The job now is to convert a Tensor to a numpy array. To do that we need to
evaluate the Tensor using its evaluate the tensor. But inorder to do that we need a to grab  a tensor flow session.

Use the `get_session()` method of the keras backend module to grab the current tensorflow session.

Here is the docstring for `get_session()`

```
def get_session():
    """Returns the TF session to be used by the backend.
    If a default TensorFlow session is available, we will return it.
    Else, we will return the global Keras session.
    If no global Keras session exists at this point:
    we will create a new global session.
    Note that you can manually set the global session
    via `K.set_session(sess)`.
    # Returns
        A TensorFlow session.
    """
```

So try:

```
def image_func(img)

    from keras import backend as K

    sess  = K.get_session()
    img = sess.run(img) # now img is a proper numpy array 

    img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV) 
    img=cv2.resize(img,(200,66))
    return img
```

**Note, I haven't been able to test this**

**EDIT**: Just tested this and it won't work (as you noticed). The lambda function needs to return
Tensor. Computation flows throw a Tensor so it also needs to be to be smooth in the sense of differentiation.

I see that essentially the lambda is changing the color and resizing the image, why don't you do this in pre-processing step?

Comment: I tested it out. But the lambda layer expects a tensor object. Specifically it says that it should be place holder. But you are returning an image. How should that be changed?