# How to use keras Lambda in a NN when using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, keras, keras-layer

I have a function

```
def preprocess(image):
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV)
  image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,  (3, 3), 0)
  image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 66))
  return image
```

I want to use this function in a Lambda layer of a NN like this

```
  model=Sequential()

  model.add(Lambda(preprocess,input_shape=(160,320,3)))
  #model.add(Lambda(lambda x: (x / 255.0) - 0.5, input_shape=(160,320,3)))
  model.add(Lambda(lambda x: (x / 255.0) - 0.5))
  model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((60,25), (0,0))))
```

However I got the error

```
model = nvidia_model()
print(model.summary())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9f6554917809> in <module>()
----> 1 model = nvidia_model()
      2 print(model.summary())

6 frames
<ipython-input-9-5e5ec9bc70c2> in preprocess(image)
      1 def preprocess(image):
      2   
----> 3   image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YUV)
      4   image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,  (3, 3), 0)
      5   image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 66))

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

How can I use this function as a layer of the NN??  (note that just using the lambda x:(x/255.0) works well.

Note: I *don't* want to do this externally. (Because I already did, it works fine, but now I am trying to do it internally)

Comment: I don't think you can, because there are no gradients associated with opencv operations. Also, processing should usually happen before model training.

Comment: All right. However normalization and cropping do work...

Comment: But you're not using opencv for those, right? You are using Keras layers, which have gradients implemented. You implemented the normalization with operations that use Keras/Tensorflow tensors, and the Cropping2D layer [is implemented in TensorFlow with tensors as well]. Those support automatic differentiation, which is necessary for model training. Numpy/opencv do not support this.

Comment: Alright. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49830980/4451521 but could not figure it out how this works