# RGB to Grayscale layer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I’m trying to utilize a rgb to grayscale layer in the function api of keras

```
grayscale_input = Lambda(lambda x: cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))(input_layer)
```

However, this solution does not work since  x is not a tensor, hence the error message

OpenCV(4.8.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'cvtColor'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

How do i make a layer that has the same function as the concept of that layer? It cannot be a preprocessing layer.

I tried converting it to a numpy array via np.array(x) but it didn’t work.

Comment: It seems that you can't use Lambda for that task and you must instantiate a custom layer like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883501/how-to-use-opencv-functions-in-keras-lambda-layer/49830980#49830980

Comment: [mre] required. cvtColor requires a numpy array. opencv APIs are not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own RGB->grayscale layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.rand(100, 150, 150, 3)

layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_sum(x*tf.constant([0.21, 0.72, 0.07]), axis=-1, keepdims=True))
model = tf.keras.Sequential([layer])

out = model(x_train)
```

The 3 values `0.21, 0.72, 0.07` are the [common multiplication values](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/) for RGB to grayscale, and then the values are summed up with `tf.reduce_sum` while retaining the axis.